# getting the result of query in AJAX/JQUERY then display it in SELECT OPTION

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to get the result of query from ajax and display it in **SELECT OPTION** with the **id="reservation_time"**

I think my ajax/jquery call is wrong, but I don't know what the proper syntax for fetching data using ajax/jquery is.
my sql statement in the **check_date.php** is working

The logic is this, The **SELECT OPTION** is hidden until the user picks a date, then it will show the available time of that particular date inside **SELECT OPTION**

RESERVATION.PHP(HTML)

```
<form action="check_temp_res.php" method="post">
            <div class="" style="width:100%;">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="temp_res_name" placeholder="Name" value="" required>
                    <input type="text" name="temp_res_number" class="form-control "onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' maxlength="11" value="" placeholder="Phone Number"required></input>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker" name="temp_res_date" placeholder="Date" value="" readonly required>

                 <select  id="reservation_time" name="reservation_time" class="form-control " required>
                        <option selected="true" value="null"disabled="disabled">TIME</option>
                        <option value=""></option>
                 </select>

                    <span id="availability" class="ftco-animate"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
             <div style="text-align: center">
                <div style="display:inline-block;">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="check" value="newsletter" disabled>
                    <label for="check">I accept the Terms and Conditions</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary button pull-left" style="" id="submit">I Understand</button>
</form>
```

AJAX/JQUERY CALL (same file)

```
<script>
    $("#reservation_time").blur(function()
    {    

        var txt = $.ajax(
            {
                url: '../api/ajax/check_date.php',
                async: true,
                type:'POST',
                data:
                {
                   res_date:$('input#datepicker').val()
                } ,
                success:function(data)
                {
                    alert(data); 
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

check_date.php

```
<?php
include '../../components/db.php';

$res_date = $_POST['res_date'];

 $query = "select t.reservation_time
from TIME_AVAILABILITY t
  left join (
    select reservation_time, reservation_date
    from RESERVATIONS
    where reservation_date = 'November 05, 2019'
  ) as q
  on t.reservation_time = q.reservation_time
where q.reservation_date is null; ";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
 echo mysqli_num_rows($result);


?>
```

Comment: use  data: JSON.stringify({res_date:$('input#datepicker').val()})

Comment: i don't know how to use JSON yet. I just started  2months ago and I have yet to tackle that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scripts are missing a few components.

The PHP code sends the correct query to the database, but it is not consuming the response from the database. In addition, it is not relaying the information to JavaScript for further consumption.

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$timeslots=array();
while ($myrow=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $timeslot=$myrow['reservation_time'];

  array_push($timeslots,$timeslot);


}

echo json_encode($timeslots);
```

Then in JavaScript where you typed "alert", parse the data:

```
var timeslots=eval('('+data+')');
```

This will give you a JavaScript array of a list of time slots.
Next you'll modify the DOM node so that your drop down contains the results. It's a bit tricky to populate INSIDE the select object. You can either use document.createElement('option'), or use .innerHTML to wipe out the select object from the outside. I'll show you the latter:

```
<div id="select_loader">
  <select id="reservation_time">...</select>
</div>

...
success:function(data){
  var timeslots=eval('('+data+')');
  var html=[];
  html.push('<select id="reservation_time">');
  for (var i=0;i<timeslots.length;i++) html.push(
    '<option value="'+timeslots[i]+'">'+timeslots[i]+'</option>');
  html.push('</select>');
  document.getElementById('select_loader').innerHTML=html.join('');
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202553/discussion-on-answer-by-ian-heisler-getting-the-result-of-query-in-ajax-jquery-t).